Medium-Small black beetle
Ive been seeing these types of beetles in my region ALOT and i really want to know which species they are.
The length is 1.5 cm, and the depth of this beetle is about 0.75 cm. There is open water, but its holes caused by cows stepping on them all the time, food sources have no droppings or chew-marks, thats all i have to say. Also, my region is Southern Brazil.
